# Active tab on Travel.SE has a giant offset circular background?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've just noticed something very odd on the Travel StackExchange site - the active tab has been given a giant and slightly off-centre blue circle around it:

[image: active]

That doesn't look correct to me, but a force-refresh doesn't make it go away, so I figure it's a new design bug that needs reporting. I'm using Firefox 37.0.02

Comment: I can reproduce this on Chrome 44 too.

Comment: I tried on both FF 37.0.02 and Chrome 42.0.23 and I could NOT reproduce the same result. I tried them on Windows 8.1, what OS are you using?

Comment: It seems to be fine now, the active tab has a sausage-like background to it, so it would seem that someone has fixed it in the last 12 hours or so